# Why can't I put wildcard to invoke a lambda function in IAM policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I need to invoke a lambda (lambdaB) from another lambda (lambdaA). In lambdaA's IAM policy, I have below configuration:

```
{
            "Action": [
                "lambda:invokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:264100014405:function:handler:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
```

It doesn't work and I got below error in lambdaA:

lambdaA is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:264100014405:handler because no identity-based policy allows the lambda:InvokeFunction action.

But if I remove the wildcard from the resource:

```
"Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:264100014405:function:handler"
            ],
```

it works fine.

lambdaA calls aws-sdk to invoke the lambda with the lambda name which is `handler`.

The reason I put a wildcard is that I'd like to grant lambdaA permission to invoke all alias on lambdaB in the future. What is the right IAM policy I should set in lambdaA's role?

Comment: But string `handler` does not match `handler:*`.  Did you try add both to `Resource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the wild card to lambdaName without the colon. like this:
`arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:264100014405:function:handler*`

It will give permissions to invoke `handler`'s all versions/aliases.

Answer (score 1):

You have a slight misunderstanding on the ARN for AWS Lambda functions. Change the ARN in your IAM policy to:

`arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:264100014405:function:YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME`

You can find `YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME` in the AWS console or use the aws-cli and call `aws lambda list-functions`.

### Explanation

An ARN for a Lambda function consists of:

`arn:aws:lambda:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:function:FUNCTION_NAME`

When using an alias or version, you can append those:

- `arn:aws:lambda:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:function:FUNCTION_NAME:ALIAS`
- `arn:aws:lambda:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:function:FUNCTION_NAME:VERSION`

You can read more [in the Lambda documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-api-permissions-ref.html)

The `handler` for a Lambda function is a configuration variable as far as Lambda is concerned. It does not play a role in Arns. If you use the aws-cli to perform a `aws lambda list-functions` command, you would see the handler as a separate propery from the ARN. For example, for each function:

```json
{
  "FunctionName": "stack-overflow-func",
  "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:111111111111:function:stack-overflow-func",
  "Runtime": "python3.9",
  "Role": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/role-name-3IJQ",
  "Handler": "handler.lambda_handler",
  ...
}
```

Comment: when i need to invoke a lambda, do I specify the function arn with or without the `version/alias` at the end?